# Recommended Approach to Creating RabbitMQ Artifacts when deploying app based on MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am looking to start on a feature in my current application which is utilizing MassTransit with RabbitMQ as the messaging provider.  I am wondering what are the recommended practices on possibly scripting out the creation of the RabbitMQ artifacts that MassTransit requires as part of my install script?  My concern is that if the system is not brought up in the proper order, messages may be published before my consumer has been brought up and started their subscription, thus possibly missing some messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our experience, we deploy the services prior to the deployment of any initiating applications (such as a public API, scheduled trigger, etc.) that would send messages to any of the service entry points. We do this to ensure that all of the environmental settings, configurations, etc. are as expected and to verify the configuration of the things like RabbitMQ, clustering, etc.

I highly recommend this approach, as it gives operations time to review and understand the new architecture, as you aren't immediately addressing any programming issues and can focus on the setup and configuration.

We also use `Fooidity` to deploy code and keep the new behavior unavailable until it is enabled for customer use. By using a feature toggle, there is no chance of any public user hitting an endpoint until it is ready for production use.

We *never* try to script out the environment and pre-configure the queues, exchanges, etc. as it just gets screwed up and we end up resetting the virtual host to let MT set it up right. I'm not saying it's impossible, it's just easier to let MT configure everything.